# Set a rule for grow region in eCognition

Tags: merge, ecognition, rule-based

I am using the grow region algorithm in eCognition sofrware in order to merge my candidate class.

I want to set the rule : two candidated objects are merged only if the length/width ratio of the target object increases after the merging.

How can I perform this rule?

[image: The grow region algorithm setting]